# Infinite loop when calling form submit() from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have customised the login page so that it will fill in the username & password from the URL parameters, see [here](https://compounding.discountchemist.com.au/my-account/?email=your@email.com).
It works fine, but I want it to automatically to log the user in (submit the form). It becomes an infinite loop though.

This is my code so far. It takes the form with class `.woocommerce-form`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var r = /([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/g; //matches second part email
    var email = r.exec(window.location.href)[0];  //gets the email from url
    if (email){
        $("input[name=username]").val(email);
        $("input[name=password]").val(email);
        $(".woocommerce-form").unbind().submit(); //INFINITE LOOP
    }       
});
```

I have tried to add the `.unbind()` to `.submit()` to prevent loading the code again, but it doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated <3

Comment: Use the debuggger to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

I have debugged your code.The problem is you have not mentioned action attribute in your form.So when you submit it will reload the same page.Add action attribute in form. Example:-

```
<form action="/action_page" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Hmm.. The normal behaviour of the form is from WooCommerce, and the action logic therefore probably comes from somewhere else, as the form works as expected when physically clicking the Log In (submit) button (when my `$(".woocommerce-form").unbind().submit();` is not in use. Any further info?